# Linking to GIS Analytics Survey from GIS SE?

Tags: discussion, surveys

I'm currently working with a team of MBA students to conduct research in the GIS industry. We have visited a few conferences and have conducted approximately 100 interviews with contacts in a variety of industries. We are currently designing a brief survey for GIS professionals to get a sense of how they utilize GIS usage and performance analytics and ideally would love to post a link here.

However, we want to respect the rules of the site and thus wanted to see what would be the best way to share such a survey with GIS professionals?

Comment: This might be [related](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/43878/7424).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend posting the link on [GIS Stack Exchange Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com). The rules on the main GIS SE site are designed to encourage a focused Q&A forum. GIS SE Chat, on the other hand, does not have these limitations. Keep in mind you will need 20 reputation to post in [chat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (i.e. two up votes for answering questions or 4 up votes for asking questions). At 100 reputation you can create your own [chat room](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), which may be better for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for asking before posting your link.

I migrated your question from the Main GIS SE site to here in Meta GIS SE because there it risked heading towards advertising, and thus would have been deleted.

Posting a link to a survey here in Meta would be off-topic too, but at least we can suggest you an alternative or two.

[@Aaron has already answered](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4359/115) with the one which I think would be the most suitable for you which is the [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).

The other alternative might be to post a [Community Promotion Ad](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/community-promotion-ads-2016) which links to your survey.  However, the problem with that is that it may or may not get voted by the community as something that it wants to run, and it needs a nett vote of +6 before it can run at all.